# coloring tail output bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a chat script which is using

```
tail -f chatlog.txt
```

to display the chat. The messages are written so that when you echo it, it outputs as colored text.

chatlog.txt:

```
20:39 \033[4;33musername\033[0m: so with all of my experience
20:39 \033[4;33musername\033[0m: we shall prevail
20:40 \033[4;33musername\033[0m: the taxi jobs are very
20:40 \033[4;33musername\033[0m: yes
21:02 \033[4;34mJacob\033[0m has joined the chat!
```

if I display using this code it works fine:

```
var=$(tail chatlog.txt)
echo -e "$var"
```

[image: output of the code]

But if I display it with `tail -f chatlog.txt` there is no color. I have tried other solutions but none seemed to work.

Comment: BTW, `echo -e` is unlike most bashisms which merely extend POSIX; by contrast, `echo -e` doing anything other than printing `-e` on output is an outright violation of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which specifies that *Implementations shall not support any options* -- and then specifies an allowance for `-n` (not as an option, but as an operand which makes behavior undefined when present at the beginning of the list), but makes no allowances for `-e`.

Comment: See also the APPLICATION USAGE section of the above-linked specification, which explicitly indicates that `printf` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output contains literal escape sequences; thus, all you need is a program which will recognize those and replace them with the characters they refer to. In POSIX-compliant shells, `printf %b` will perform this operation.

Thus:

```
tail -f chatlog.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%b\n' "$line"; done
```

See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a general discussion of the `while read` mechanism. To call out some of the important points:

- Using `IFS=` prevents leading and trailing whitespace from being trimmed from lines.
- Using the `-r` argument to `read` prevents literal backslashes from being removed by `read`.